# PHP : how to remove certain portion of the String in an array

Tags: php

I have this array

```
$address[] =  $row['name'].",".$row['locality_name'].",".$row['city_name']
```

The output is

> Ashirwad Estate, Goregaon (w), Mumbai

I want to remove the `(w)` string from the output

How should I use a function with `$row['locality_name']` to trim/remove that?

Comment: Can you post some more relevant inputs and expected output. As of now you can use `str_replace` over here.

Comment: which Functions i can use and how....??

Comment: output - Ashirwad Estate , Goregaon -west , Mumbai

same function Should also be able to remove  '-west'  from the output

Comment: I am assuming this "(w)" appears in more than one input. If so it would be better to pass a regular expression to check all inputs. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: what other strings do you have that you need removed, except for `(w)` and `-west` ?

Comment: I want to remove everything that comes after a special character like ( - Including the characters

Comment: Not to be mean, but if that's something you need to ask how to do, you should let a developer do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more general answer

```
$row['locality_name'] = preg_replace("/\(.*\)/", "", $row['locality_name']);
```

or better

```
$address[] =  sprintf(
    "%s,%s,%s",
    $row['name'],
    preg_replace("/\(.*\)/", "", $row['locality_name']),
    $row['city_name']
);
```

Regex explanation

```
\( // escapes open bracket
.* // matches every char from zero to infinite times
\) // escapes closing bracket
```

Comment: This won't work with strings  like as `Ashirwad Estate, Goregaon (w), Mumbai(west)` this results into `Ashirwad Estate, Goregaon` instead of  `Ashirwad Estate, Goregaon , Mumbai`

Comment: I guess, You forgot to consider the `space`. :)

Comment: @Uchiha locality name is only Goregaon (w)

Comment: I mean the `space` between `Goregaon` & `(w)`

Comment: @DonCallisto but what if there exist same consequences

Comment: That's not for the answer. The comment by Uchiha instead.

Comment: @Uchiha: that's no problem at all with other sequences in the same array element. just test my code with a different portion of test after brackets; you'll find this works like a charm :)

Comment: i just want the answer to be like this Ashirwad Estate,Goregaon,Mumbai.

I dont need spaces anyway

Comment: @PrathameshSarang: just strip them off from sprintf. Take a look to my update

Comment: @uchiha   preg_replace("/\(.*\)/", "", $row2['locality_name']) this works to remove (w) but i also want to remove string after hyphen -west in some cases

Answer (score 1):

```
$toRemove = array("(w)","(W)","(West)","(west)");
$row['locality_name'] = str_replace($toRemove, "", $row['locality_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` with the following regex

```
\s*(\([^)]+\)|\-\w+)
```

So your code looks like as

```
echo preg_replace("/\s*(\([^)]+\)|\-\w+)/","","Ashirwad Estate, Goregaon (w), Mumbai");
```

Comment: so will i get outout like this 
Ashirwad Estate, Goregaon, Mumbai for this  Ashirwad Estate, Goregaon (w), Mumbai and even if it is like this Ashirwad Estate, Goregaon -west, Mumbai

Comment: Nope this'll remove those characters that came between `paranthesis ()` and not with the `-words`

Comment: Check my answer instead